# Linux O.S. : Where is the firefox setting stored for this browser modification preference?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, centos, gnome

In your firefox if you right click on the top panel next to 'Help' you can uncheck

```
Menu Bar
```

this makes firefox better looking to me.

i need to know where this setting is stored however.

i looked at my file at

```
gedit /root/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
```

but it was not stored in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toolbar-menubar` in `localstore.rdf`:

```
 <RDF:Description RDF:about="chrome://browser/content/browser.xul#toolbar-menubar"
               currentset="menubar-items"
               autohide="true" />
```

Comment: No, that's Mozilla's XML User Interface Language (XUL)! [Chrome_URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL)